# HTML/CSS How to make element transparent for one element but overlay another

Tags: html, css

So, I have this HTML+CSS:

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I need to make green square transparent for background but overlay red square. And I need to have it variable so I cannot do it like this: `.div2 {background-color: lightblue;}`. Is it passible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Use gradient for the red square:</strike>

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background:
     linear-gradient(red,red) right /20px 100%,
     linear-gradient(red,red) bottom /100% 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
```

**Update**

You are probably looking for something like this:

```css
body {
    background: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1069) fixed;
}
.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
}

.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/600?image=1069) fixed;
    animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes change {
 to{top:100px;left:100px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
```

Comment: This is not what Im searching for. I would explain it but its complicated.

Comment: @MataxePlay if you cannot explain we cannot help :) Am providing a solution based on the data I have. Try to bring the complexity so we can understand

Comment: @MataxePlay I have updated my answer, you can check if it's what you need

Comment: Thanks! This is what I need! But I think there willbe some problems but I make it yourself :D Thanks once more!
And I need it for circle progress bar. I want it like thin strap in circle, like border and there I need to cover inner side of circle. Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-color: inherit;` for the overlay.

```css
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already tried it before but it was not working. And now its good :D But one more problem... Im need it for image :/ And I cannot set the div to image becase need to move it on the screen with image background..